# Pagination - how to make it more dynamic

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm trying to create dynamic page links, I currently have it like this...

```
  <c:forEach var="page" begin="1" end="10">
    <a href="/servletmapping/${page}">${page} </a>
  </c:forEach>
```

On each page there are 10 rows, thus using the above code allows you to see 100.

How can I make it more dynamic? Let say, if I had 200 rows in the DB, I wouldn't be able to go to page 11 without changing the end value... obviously thats not convienient.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<c:forEach var="page" begin="1" end="${myBean.lastPage}">`

where `getLastPage` is defined as

```
public int getLastPage() {
    int result = list.size() / NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
    if (list.size() % NUMBER_OF_ITEMS_PER_PAGE > 0) {
        result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```